# Map set different types of value depending on key type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use Map to implement a Trie, so I created a TrieNodeMap type. The TrieNodeMap has two types of keys: a single letter OR a '$' which means the end of a word.
Key with a letter maps inner TrieNodeMap and '$' maps word's info object.

This is what I wrote:

```
type Char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' // just name a few chars;
type TrieNodeMap = Map<Char, TrieNodeMap> | Map<'$', object>;
```

However, when I try to use it, the editor shows an error around `'a' as Char`: "TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'."

```
let node: TrieNodeMap = new Map();
node.set('a' as Char, new Map());
```

Have I done something wrong, why it seems that the key of TrieNodeMap is a never type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to overload your `Map`. In other words, you need to use intersection `&` instead of union `|`

```js
type Char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' // just name a few chars;
type TrieNodeMap = Map<Char, TrieNodeMap> & Map<'$', object>;

let node: TrieNodeMap = new Map();
node.set('a', new Map());

const trie = node.get('b') // TrieNodeMap | undefined
const obj = node.get('$') // object | undefined
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WY4Zgm)